# Java 7 sun.* classes with Java 8

Tags: java

I am using some library which inside itself use sun.security.* classes. And I'm using it as dependency in my project which is java 8. In java 8 some methods removed from sun classes which my library need.

I understand that messing up with sun.* packages is not good idea, but I don't want to downgrade my project to java 7, so is there any workaround to make my project run in java 8 environment, but use sun.* classes from java 7 ?

Comment: Piece of advice:  Don't code against implementation details as those details can change.  Incidentally, they explicitly warn you not to rely on sun.* and com.sun.* classes.

Comment: If the latest version of that library, supports Java 8, upgrade to it.

Comment: This is why you don't use `sun.*` classes. There is no good way to do what you want to do without running the risk of breaking your JVM. If you tell us what you're using them for, there may be another way, though.

Comment: depending on the scale of your problem: implement wrappers using the replacement classes from java8 in your own `sun.*` packages

Comment: @EvdzhanMustafa I'm already use latest version of library. But library supports only java 7

Comment: @dcsohl Yes, I know, that I should not use them, but I have a library which use them to connect to google bigtable. It use google oauth2 api. And this library failed with java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.getRawHostnameSE()Ljava/lang/String so i'm trying to find a workaround to make this work with java 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... is there any workaround to make my project run in java 8 environment, but use sun.* classes from java 7 ?

The missing method is part of the SSL implementation, and it looks like there have been major rewrites in Java 8.  (For good reason, IIRC.)

Is there a simple workaround?

Probably not.  It would entail messing around with the SSL implementation, and that is risky, even if you can get the code to run.

A couple of better ideas would be:

- Port the 3rd-party library that is causing you problems to Java 8.  (Or pay someone else to do it for you.)
- Change it to use a different OAuth2 API.  There are some leads here: http://oauth.net/2/